# Pirate booty distribution's distribution function

Tags: discrete-data, multivariate-distribution

I would like to know if the following multivariate discrete distribution has an established name and how to generate it.

Let the sample $(X_i)_{i\in{1..n}}$ drawn from this distribution have the following properties:

- $X_i \in \{0, 1, ..., m\}, \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m$
- all the ($X_i$) combinations are equiprobable.

Think of it as the repartition of a pirate booty: there are $m$ items ordered by price to be distributed among $n$ pirates. The captain takes the $X_1$ most expensive items (from none to the whole booty), the captain in second takes the following $X_2$ most expensive items from the remaining booty and so on.

The analogy with the pirates stops here. Because of the third condition above, the marginalized probability of $X_1$ being 0 must be the same as that of $X_n$, which is unlikely to happen with pirates !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $Y_i=X_i+1$.  The $Y_i$ therefore are a sequence of $n$ strictly positive integers that sum to $n+m$.  Such a sequence is called a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $m+n$.

Any composition corresponds to another sequence $(k)=k_0, k_1, \ldots, k_n$ of $n+1$ integers with

$$0=k_0 \lt k_1\lt k_2 \lt \cdots \lt k_{n-1}\lt k_n=n+m.$$

The correspondence is that $k_i$ is the partial sum

$$k_i = Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_i$$

and each of the original values $X_i$ can be recovered as $$X_i = k_{i}-k_{i-1}-1;\quad i=1,2,\ldots,n.$$

Now any such sequence $(k)$ determines and is determined by the subset $\{k_1,k_2,\ldots, k_{n-1}\}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n+m-1\}$.  There are (by definition) $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$ such subsets.

**Your distribution is uniform on these subsets.**  It is, in effect, the distribution of samples of $1, 2, \ldots, n+m-1$ of size $n-1$ taken without replacement.

We may therefore draw the $X_i$ by selecting such a sample at random, sorting its values (to produce the $k_i$), computing their differences, and subtracting $1$ from each.  There are many well-known ways to obtain such samples, so I won't dwell on that detail.  (For efficiency, you might want to select a method that produces the sample already in sorted order.)

---

Here is working code in `R` to produce a single such realization of the $X_i$.  It calls on the `sample.int` function to obtain a random sample without replacement.

```
#
# Random compositions of `m` into `n` parts of size 0 or larger.
#
rcomposition <- function(m, n)
  diff(c(0, sort(sample.int(m+n-1, n-1)), n+m)) - 1
```

As an example of its use, the next code snippet specifies values of $n$ and $m$ and (reproducibly) requests 1000 realizations of the $X_i$, storing them in successive columns of the output array `x`:

```
n <- 3
m <- 4
set.seed(17)
x <- replicate(1e3, rcomposition(m, n))
```

We can check the output for uniformity by tallying the number of appearances of each composition.

```
#
# Tally the columns of `x`.
#
i <- table(apply(x, 2, paste0, collapse=ifelse(m > 9, ",", "")))
N <- choose(m+n-1, n-1)
i <- c(i, rep(0, N - length(i))) # Include any zero counts explicitly
if (length(i) <= 80) print(i)
```

Here's the output for this particular simulation.  The `print` statement displayed the tally of all $\binom{3+4-1}{3-1}=15$ possible compositions:

```
004 013 022 031 040 103 112 121 130 202 211 220 301 310 400 
 58  69  85  68  69  69  64  60  69  73  64  59  70  69  54
```

The top row shows the compositions; for instance, the first entry `004` corresponds to $X_1=X_2=0,\ X_3=4$.  The bottom row gives their counts.

There is variation in the counts because this is, after all, a random process.  Is the amount of variation acceptable?  A chi-squared test works well for large simulations (more than $5\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$ will do fine).

```
#
# Check the tally for uniformity.
#
chisq.test(i, p=rep(1/N, N))
```

Here is the result for this particular simulation:

> X-squared = 11.54, df = 14, p-value = 0.6432

The p-value is not extremely small, showing the counts do not differ significantly from uniformity.

Comment: Fantastic answer, so elegant!