Algorithm to enumerate distribution of $n$ balls in $m$ bins?
I am reasoning through a kind of sample space. My inquiry will be assisted by an algorithm which can enumerate—ideally with some kind of ordering—the possible ways to distribute $n$ balls among $m$ bins, where $m > n$. For example, suppose $n=3$ and $m=5$, here is one distribution:
 1 2 3 4 5
|o|o| | |o |

Here's another with two balls in bin 2:
 1 2 3 4 5
| |o| | | |
| |o|o| | |

I know the number of possible distributions get very big as $m$ and $n$ increase, but when I think about ways I might enumerate solutions I get stuck in Towers of Hanoi type solutions, but these seem to either mass multiple balls landing in the same bin towards the ends, or move them across the range of bins in one big mass.

My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/310824/919 provides code to produce random compositions.  By setting the sample size equal to the number of all compositions it will output them all.  The analysis there shows how simple it is to enumerate them.  You could use the built-in combn function to enumerate them systematically.  A single subset of ${1,2,\ldots,N},$ given as a sorted vector $k,$ is converted to a composition with the expression diff(c(0, k, N)) - 1. As a check, the resulting vector $x$ is converted back to a sorted vector with head(cumsum(x + 1), -1).

+1 @whuber Thank you so much (as per usual :). The linked Wikipedia article on compositions (combinatorics) has some beautifully intuitive  images to aid in understanding these!

The total number of such compositions can be found using stars and bars and is ${m+n-1 \choose n}$.  How you list them is up to you:  @BenBolker's list has them in a kind of lexicographic order (smallest numbers first when reading right-to-left) but there are many other potential choices.

I think these are compositions. The partitions package (GitHub repository here), with the specific source code here (it calls the blockparts function internally).
library(partitions)
t(compositions(3,5))
               
 [1,] 3 0 0 0 0
 [2,] 2 1 0 0 0
 [3,] 1 2 0 0 0
 [4,] 0 3 0 0 0
 [5,] 2 0 1 0 0
 [6,] 1 1 1 0 0
 [7,] 0 2 1 0 0
 [8,] 1 0 2 0 0
 [9,] 0 1 2 0 0
[10,] 0 0 3 0 0
[11,] 2 0 0 1 0
[12,] 1 1 0 1 0
[13,] 0 2 0 1 0
[14,] 1 0 1 1 0
[15,] 0 1 1 1 0
[16,] 0 0 2 1 0
[17,] 1 0 0 2 0
[18,] 0 1 0 2 0
[19,] 0 0 1 2 0
[20,] 0 0 0 3 0
[21,] 2 0 0 0 1
[22,] 1 1 0 0 1
[23,] 0 2 0 0 1
[24,] 1 0 1 0 1
[25,] 0 1 1 0 1
[26,] 0 0 2 0 1
[27,] 1 0 0 1 1
[28,] 0 1 0 1 1
[29,] 0 0 1 1 1
[30,] 0 0 0 2 1
[31,] 1 0 0 0 2
[32,] 0 1 0 0 2
[33,] 0 0 1 0 2
[34,] 0 0 0 1 2
[35,] 0 0 0 0 3
```


+1 Thank you! I am finding the provided output very useful.
